# How to use async.eachSeries in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, each, async.js

I want to iterate through a list of items in a synchronous manner and use the result of each step in the next step. I can someone correct/suggest the code logic which I am using?

```
const async = require('async')

async.eachSeries([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  function downloadChunk (chunkID, asyncCallback) {
    console.log(chunkID)
    const result = `This is a result from ${chunkID} call and should be used somewhere in ${chunkID + 1}`
    // How should I pass this result to next step
    asyncCallback()
  },
  function complete (err) {
    if (err) console.log('Error: ' + err)
    console.log('this is the end. All the variables have been used')
  }
)
```

Comment: `async.eachSeries` works through a list **asynchronously**. Maybe sequentially, but not synchronously. Is your `downloadChunk` function actually asynchronous? Because if it's not, just use a normal loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a variable outside the async.eachSeries like so:

```
const async = require('async')
var result = null;

async.eachSeries([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    function downloadChunk (chunkID, asyncCallback) {
        console.log(chunkID)
        console.log('Result from previous call', result);

        // reassign new value to the result
        result = `This is a result from ${chunkID} call and should be used somewhere in ${chunkID + 1}`

        asyncCallback()
    },
    function complete (err) {
        if (err) console.log('Error: ' + err)
        console.log('this is the end. All the variables have been used')
    }
)
```